Need help in preparing for first meeting with PhD supervisor
I have recently received a reply for PhD application from University of Alabama, USA. The PhD supervisor had replied with Thank you for interest in his group. He then asked me about availability for Teams meeting and encouraged me to submit application at the same time.
Now, I am trying to figure out how to prepare for Teams Meeting with him and as I am preparing for Fall 2025 admission, so what type of questions will be asked from me and how to convince him for my Fall 2025 availability with funded opportunity? Is he willing to accept me as his student?
Note : The area of interest is in Power Electronics in Electrical Engineering.

Sorry, this is a question far to specific an the inidividual to be answerable here.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5864/how-to-prepare-and-what-is-discussed-with-professors-at-a-phd-interview-session here a related questino

I don't understand what he meant by submitting application at the same time? Do anybody understand?
